# 'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat' Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Please help i dont know why i keep getting this.  I get the error all the way at the bottom whre the 2 is.  I don't think i can edit that.  If anyone could help me out that would be great.
EDit: Added all of the code.  Thanks for helping me

( don't mind this , it's telling me to add more detail, welp )

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
 @State private var Waifus = ["Rem","Chika","Zero Two","SpeedWagon"].shuffled()
@State private var CorrectGirl = Int.random(in: 0...2)

@State private var ShowingScore = false
@State private var ScoreTitle = ""
@State private var Points = 0

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        .background(Color.black)

        VStack(spacing: 30) {

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Tap The Waifu")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Text(Waifus[CorrectGirl])
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.black)

            }
            ForEach(0 ..< 4 ) { number in
                Button(action: {
                    self.WaifuTapped(number)
                }) {
                    Image(self.Waifus[number])
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .frame(width: 88, height: 88)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth : 4))



                }
            }
            Text("You have")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Text("\(Points) Points")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.black)

            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $ShowingScore) {
        Alert(title: Text(ScoreTitle),message: Text("Your Score is \(Points)"),dismissButton:
            .default(Text("Countinue Weeb")) {
                self.askQuestion()
            })
    }
}
func WaifuTapped(_ number : Int) {
    if number == CorrectGirl {
        ScoreTitle = "Correct"
        Points += 1
    } else {
        ScoreTitle = "Wrong, The Waifu was \(self.Waifus[number])"
    }

    ShowingScore = true
}

func askQuestion() {
    Waifus.shuffle()
    CorrectGirl = Int.random(in: 0...2)

}
```

}

Comment: lineWidth : CGFloat(2)

Comment: That didn't work it said "unresolved identifier GCFloat"

Comment: @CalebThePerson import Foundation, then lineWidth : CGFloat(2)

Comment: really you have mistake at some other line of code. *Errors in SwiftUI often shows at the wrong places*. show us full code, please.

Comment: @АлександрГрабовский I added my full code

Comment: @byaruhaf i did that and i managed ot get another error .  Where it says ".fontWeight(.black) .  it's telling me 'Font.Weight' is not convertible to 'Font.Weight?'

Comment: Can you please check you have written '.background(Color.black)' directly inside ZStack. If you want to apply it then apply after the ZStack completion.

Comment: @kchopda oh yeah I forgot that XD . I forgot to remove it thanks for remaining me .  anything else wrong :?

Comment: @CelebThePerson There nothing wrong except that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll show only `body`, where the mistake is:

```swift
// ... variables and other
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
//            .background(Color.black) // this is the wrong line of code
//            it should be after "{" after ZStack
//            sure, you can use just "Rectangle()"

            VStack(spacing: 30) {

                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Tap The Waifu")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Text(Waifus[CorrectGirl])
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.black)

                }
                ForEach(0 ..< 4 ) { number in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.WaifuTapped(number)
                    }) {
                        Text("")
                        Image(self.Waifus[number])
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .frame(width: 88, height: 88)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth : 4))



                    }
                }
                Text("You have")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("\(Points) Points")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.black)

                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .background(Color.black) // it should be here
        .alert(isPresented: $ShowingScore) {
            Alert(title: Text(ScoreTitle),message: Text("Your Score is \(self.Points)"),dismissButton:
                .default(Text("Countinue Weeb")) {
                    self.askQuestion()
                })
        }
    }
```

As I said in comments: errors in SwiftUI show at the wrong places. The advice to avoid them: extract your views in `body` to other structs and it should be much easier to handle everything

**UPDATE** that was the only mistake, now it works. I think you just need to replace `.background(..` with `Rectangle()`. I only pointed you the wrong line of code.

[image]